# Let $N$ be even integer. Is there a solution for $x$ if $\sin(nx) = 0$ for all integer $n > N$, but $\sin(Nx) \neq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let $N$ be even integer. Is there a solution for $x$ if $\sin(nx) = 0$ for all integer $n > N$, but $\sin(Nx) \neq 0$

Is there a solution to this? I suppose if a solution exist, it needs to be a multiple of $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, this could only happen if $x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$ to evaluate to $0$ for all large enough $n$. You can see this by noting that it at least must be a rational multiple of $\pi$, and you can take some prime number larger than the denominator to obtain a multiple of $\pi$ with the same denominator, but since it evaluates to $0$ it is an integer multiple, hence must have been one in the first place. But then $Nx$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$, so $\sin Nx=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Then $\sin(2Nx)=0=2\sin(Nx)\cos(Nx)$ but $\sin(Nx)\neq 0$ so $\cos(Nx)=0$ but then $$\sin((N+1)x)=0=\sin(Nx+x)=\sin(Nx)\cos(x)+\sin(x)\cos(Nx)=\sin(Nx)\cos(x)$$ but $\sin(Nx)\neq 0$ so $\cos(x)=0$ so $x=\pi/2+k\pi$

But we can see that $x=\pi/2 +k\pi$ doesn't satisfy this for any $N$ hence a contradiction (Sorry for the excessive buts).